# Rails: how to set last login datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have datetime column named lastlogin in my User table. How can I set (and update) this data when user loggined in?
I'm triyng something like this in my session controller:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    user.lastlogin = Time.now
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

user.lastlogin = Time.now not works :(

Comment: I have answer to my question, I forget about user.save.
Maybe it will be usefull for someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user.update_attribute(:lastlogin, Time.now)
```

Comment: great :) when you want to update only one attribute then I recommend this method. It works the same but it looks better ;)

Comment: `user.touch(:lastlogin)` looks even better... *and* updates `updated_at`.

Comment: In Rails 4, you can use `user.update_columns(:lastlogin => Time.now)`.  That will update _only_ the columns specified, without any callbacks, validations, nor will it update the `updated_at` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `user.touch :lastlogin` ([touch](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch))

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
user.update_attribute(:lastlogin, Time.now)
```

will work well.

Depending if the date will be used by the user or by you, I'll add that one rails best practices would be to use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now` (one gives the date *in the time zone specified by config.time_zone in application.rb* , the other gives the user local time).

Source: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2014/10/22/use-time-zone-now-instead-of-time-now/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have to save the user in order to make it persistence. Just add `user.save` before `user.lastlogin = Time.now`.

Comment: I think, `user.lastlogin = Time.now` must be before `user.save`. Because I set Time.now and after this save new data. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Putting this together, I'm doing the following.

1. User has a last_seen_on field (I'm using Date rather than DateTime)
2. Create method to update last_seen_on
3. Call it when you do a login

My update method is as follows

```
  def update_last_seen_on
    if self.last_seen_on != Date.today
      self.update_column(:last_seen_on,Date.today)
    end
  end
```

This ensures that

- the database is only called when there is a change
- no callbacks are triggered on the user model
- updated at is not changed

If you're using Devise, then you can call this easily by adding the following in your Devise initialiser

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  user.update_last_seen_on
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely think that most of these solutions work well, but this is how I did it at a more granular level that's slightly different than some of the other responses.

1. Create a migration by running `rails g migration AddLastLoginToUsers last_login:datetime` in the console.
2. That should generate a migration file that looks like:

```
class AddLastLoginToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :last_login, :datetime
  end
end
```

3. Next, run `rails db:migrate` in the console.
4. Find where your new session is being created (probably in your SessionsController, if it's following convention). In the create action, add `user.update_column(:last_login, Time.zone.now)`

The advantage of using update_column here is multi-part. It skips validations, callbacks, and it also doesn't update any additional fields, so it's a fast and less convoluted process. Each time a user creates a session in the future, it will modify the new attribute, and that should take care of most simple requirements.